# Which algorithm Kubernetes uses to nevigate traffics in replicaset/deployment

Tags: kubernetes, replicaset, kubernetes-deployment

I was asked about it, and I couldn't find info about it online - Which algorithm Kubernetes uses to nevigate traffics in replicaset or deployment (I guess that they the same) for pods?

Lets say, I have replica of 5 pods in my Kubernetes cluster, defined in replicaset. How does the cluster pick which pod to go to, in new request? Is it uses round-robin? I couldn't find info about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithm applied to determine which pod will process the request depends on ***kube-proxy*** mode that is running.

- In 1.0, the proxy works in mode called userspace and default algorithm is round robin.
- In 1.2 mode iptables proxy was added, but still round robin is used due to iptables limitations.
- In 1.8.0-beta, IP Virtual Server (IPVS) was introduced, it allow much more algorithms options, like:

  - RoundRobin;
  - WeightedRoundRobin;
  - LeastConnection;
  - WeightedLeastConnection;
  - LocalityBasedLeastConnection;
  - LocalityBasedLeastConnectionWithReplication;
  - SourceHashing;
  - DestinationHashing;
  - ShortestExpectedDelay;
  - NeverQueue.

References:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies
https://sookocheff.com/post/kubernetes/understanding-kubernetes-networking-model/